# Magento 2 products are added through admin panel,but its not showing in the frontsite?

Tags: magento2, category, category-products

I have created the **categories** and **subcategories** after that I have added the products and assigned each product under some categories, but it is not showing on the front website when clicking the categories link?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2 You should Run the below commands to re-index so that you can view product in frontend

from magento2 root folder

```
:php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: If each time re-indexing is needed then how we can delivered to the client,client is not having much more technical knowledge. Is there any permanent solution for this?